# DocumentDb feedResponse.ResponseContinuation JSON

Tags: c#, azure, pagination, azure-cosmosdb

When I get continuation token while querying Documents on DocumentDb NoSQL database I get feedResponse.ResponseContinuation JSON

```html
{
    "token":"+RID:r+xQAPHUJQANAAAAAAAAAA==#RT:1#TRC:10#FPC:AQ0AAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAA=",
    "range":{"min":"","max":"FF"}
}
```

Could you please explain what each field means? And how the values are set/ calculated? Is the `"token"` value encrypted?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could you please explain what each field means? And how the values
>   set/ calculated ? Is "token" value encrypted?

Presence of continuation token in response headers means there's more data available for the request you made.

**You should not try to interpret this value and treat it as `Opaque`**. By `opaque` what I mean to say is that you should not build your business logic around this continuation token's value because in my experience, you will receive different values under different circumstances.

For example, we receive following tokens under different circumstances:

In one instance, we received the following:

> {"token":"-RID:4pVnPNKLRAAGAAAAAAAAAA==#RT:1#TRC:2","range":{"min":"","max":"FF"}}.

Yet, in another instance we received the following:

> {"token":null,"range":{"min":"05D1A53CB92960","max":"05D1B53CB92960"}}.

And then there's another one:

> +RID:4pVnAO6fMNADAAAAAACAAQ==#RT:1#TRC:2#FPC:ALMABAAAAIABAwAAAAAAgAE=

As you can see, there's no rhyme or reason behind the value of this token.

What your code should do is check for the existence of continuation token in response headers and if it is there then include this in your next request to get next set of data.